# Swift - Dependency injection in View Controller with Network calls and Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, uiviewcontroller

Swift - How can I implement dependency injection in View Controller that is created from a Storyboard and the data that should be injected is fetched from the Network (will be available following async call)?

For example, View Controller shows a list. In order to get the data set for the list, a network call should be performed and when then data injected into the dataSet property.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is that a separation of YourVC class and network class? Means there will no instance member of the network class in yourVC, right?

Comment: I can add a network class

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if quite got your question, but here is how I usually do. Suppose you have a class `DataFetcher`, responsible for making the network calls:

```
class DataFetcher {

     func fetchData(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
         // Code to fetch the data
     }

}
```

And in your view controller, hold a reference to a `DataFetcher` type and make it injectable by having a static method to instantiate the ViewController:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    private static let identifier = "MyViewController"

    var fetcher: DataFetcher?

    static func newInstance(fetcher: DataFetcher) -> MyViewController {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! MyViewController
        controller.fetcher = fetcher
        return controller
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
    }

    private func fetchData() {
        fetcher?.fetchData { [weak self] data in
            // Reaload data of tableView, CollectionView, etc
        }
    }

}
```

Then, whenever you want to present that ViewController, call the `newInstance` method:

```
let fetcher = DataFetcher()
let controller = MyViewController.newInstance(fetcher: fetcher) // Injecting
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```